# Choosing 4 integers in increasing order from a set of n integers

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is a set with n distinct integers, suppose I would like to choose a tuple of 4 integers with the following restriction

1. $(a,b,c,d)$
2. $d>c$, $c>b$, $c>a$

If in this case, could I say the number of tuples are $n\choose 4$ $\cdot 2$ because for every such tuple, there are 2 ways to arrange first 2 elements. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This is correct, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been stated in the comments, your approach and result are correct.